# Error: Failed to load main-class manifest attribute from

Tags: java, installation, mysql-connector

When I am installing mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin on my PC, it gives me an error such as: `failed to load main-class manifest attribute from`. Please can you tell me what should I do to remove this error? I'm not able to do anything without mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin, so please tell me as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you share some more details like which OS are you installing mysql-connector, how exactly did you try to install it, stacktrace of the error etc.  If its a jar file, you can just copy it to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to run the JAR file as if it is an executable JAR file (either by double-clicking on it or running it with a command like `java -jar mysql-connector-...jar`).

That's not what you are supposed to do with this JAR file. You just need to add it to the classpath of your project; don't try to unpack it or run it. It doesn't contain an installation program.

Background information:

Executable JAR files contain a `META-INF/MANIFEST` file that contains attributes such as `Main-Class` that tell Java what the class to run is when you run the JAR file. If the JAR file doesn't contain a manifest file, or contains a manifest file that doesn't have a `Main-Class` attribute, then it is not an executable JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

Two questions come up: 1) Is mysql-connector-java supposed to have a main class? 2)how are you trying to install it?

1) No. It it only contains JDBC classes for interacting with mysql.
2) since you get main-class attribute errors you seem to be double clicking on a jar file.

To be able to use it you have to add the jar file to your classpath.